# Mistery with DHCP of VirtualBox and CentOS 7

Tags: centos, virtualbox, dhcp

I have the latest VirtualBox installed on Windows 7 Pro. I created NatNetwork with 10.10.10.0/27 and DHCP enabled and Host-only network with 172.17.24.0/27 and DHCP enabled too.

Created Virtual Machine as Red Hat Linux and installed CentOS 7 on it.

After multiple issues for whatever reason I have a wrong IP given by DHCP server to enp0s8 interface.

This is client side:

```
[root@smu1 ~]# ifconfig enp0s8
enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.6  netmask 255.255.255.224  broadcast 10.0.2.31
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe41:58ae  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:41:58:ae  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13  bytes 3430 (3.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 207  bytes 23996 (23.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

[root@smu1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME="enp0s8"
UUID="77e14c77-358e-48c3-be0c-e18d75cecc5a"
DEVICE="enp0s8"
ONBOOT="yes"
PEERDNS=no
PEERROUTES=yes
```

This is host side:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe  list natnetworks
NetworkName:    NatNetwork
IP:             10.10.10.1
Network:        10.10.10.0/27
IPv6 Enabled:   No
IPv6 Prefix:    fd17:625c:f037:2::/64
DHCP Enabled:   Yes
Enabled:        Yes
loopback mappings (ipv4)
        127.0.0.1=2
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe  list dhcpservers
NetworkName:    HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
IP:             172.17.24.4
NetworkMask:    255.255.255.224
lowerIPAddress: 172.17.24.5
upperIPAddress: 172.17.24.30
Enabled:        Yes

NetworkName:    NatNetwork
IP:             10.10.10.4
NetworkMask:    255.255.255.224
lowerIPAddress: 10.10.10.5
upperIPAddress: 10.10.10.30
Enabled:        Yes
```

Exactly the same settings for host-only network work great! No issues at all.

```
[root@smu1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp0s3
UUID=b012704e-cc06-4ece-b4ea-7a12bed03f27
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
PEERDNS=no
PEERROUTES=no
[root@smu1 ~]# ifconfig enp0s3
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.24.6  netmask 255.255.255.224  broadcast 172.17.24.31
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe46:c2b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:46:0c:2b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 292  bytes 29717 (29.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 238  bytes 46906 (45.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I tried reboots of both host and guest, delete and re-create natnetwork and dhcp server from command line (did it once again after disabled completely UAC in Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was wrong, perhaps because I manually assigned 10.10.10.4 as DHCP server IP and VirtualBox doesn't like it...
I created natnet1 from GUI for another network, deleted 10.10.10.0/27 from CMD, tested that DHCP is now giving proper IP from network natnet1, created natnet10 with network I originally needed and deleted natnet1.
Now the IP is assigned as expected.
DHCP server IP is 10.10.10.3 and not .4 as I manually assigned in failure scenario.
Perhaps some internal limitations from VirtualBox on which IP can be DHCP server in NatNetwork...
If anyone want to test this theory fill free.

**Problem solved.**